# Mixing javascript with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

On a click I assign a class to my element **(SVG PATH)** using pure javascript:

```
this.getElement().classList.add('active');
```

The new class is part of a series of other classes it already has. However once this new class is added to the clicked element, it should also give a class `.active` to other elements in the html which have any matching classes with the clicked element itself.

html:

```
<button class="1600 1500"></button>
<button class="1600 1300 1200"></button>
<button class="1300 1200 1700 1800"></button>    
<button class="1300 1200 1100 1900"></button>

<div class="1600 1700 item leaflet"></div>
```

I don't know which button has a matching class since those classes are dynamic too. All I know is that the div will have any class matching any button's class.

The thing is that for specific reasons I am using pure javascript to assign a new class name on click on the div (**works**):

```
this.getElement().classList.add('active');
```

So the following won't work:

```
this.click(function() {
  var classes = this.attr('class').split(' ')
  classes.forEach(function(elem) {
    $('.' + elem).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

This how i call the click:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        click: panelShow
    });
}

function panelShow(e) {
    // This works, the class is added to the clicked element
    this.getElement().classList.add('active');
}
```

But I have buttons outside this and needs to have a class active as per the question.

> Desired after the div click

```
<div class="1600 1700 item leaflet active"></div>

<button class="1600 1500 active"></button>
<button class="1600 1300 1200 active"></button>
<button class="1300 1200 1700 1800 active"></button>
<button class="1300 1200 1100 1900"></button>
```

> This is how I deal with the opposite, clicking on the buttons (and
>   works):

```
var date;
$("button").on("click", function(b) {

    date = $(this).attr("data-date");

    $('path').attr('class', function(index, classNames) {
        return classNames.replace('active', '');
    });

   $("svg ." + date).attr('class', function(index, classNames) {
        return classNames + ' active';
    });

    $(".btn").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
 });
```

**NOTE**

> In real life on the buttons I am using `data attribute` but consider it as a
>   class for the example question on here, it's just a paste from a more complex code I have.
>
> *Also I am using [leafletsJS](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html), that's why the javascript click in
>   the function above.*

Comment: @PeterRader Completely Untrue.

Comment: @PeterRader I'm looking for an alternative solution

Comment: It seems like you have made something that seems to be a lot more complicated than it seems to really need to be? Emphasis on "seems".

Comment: @rob.m PeterRader is completely wrong.

Comment: @adeneo yes i did, but taking this example how can I solve it, can you help?

Comment: @ScottMarcus No you are wrong!

Comment: @PeterRader jQuery IS JavaScript and jQuery has many API points that return native DOM objects.

Comment: @PeterRader Are you intentionally attempting to mislead people?

Comment: I have updated my question with an example of my real case*

Comment: `this` inside your example's click function refers to a different `this` than you think. Either replace the function by an arrow function, or `bind(this)` to your function.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, why aren't you doing `$(this).addClass('active')`, I'm assuming `on()` is from jQuery here, and then get the classes and attach the active class

Comment: I should check in pure javascript `.ClassList` and do so for the clicked element and the buttons to check against. How tho, i don't know. That's why jQuery is there but that's wrong.

Comment: Something like this maybe -> https://jsfiddle.net/89yadm4c/

Comment: @adeneo i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined(…)

Comment: Please revise your question and try to put these on your question: 1. What is the desired final functional behaviour you are trying to achieve? 2. Use meaningful classnames instead of valueA & valueB, as it would be much helpful

Comment: @Trix you are right, updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

```
var buttons = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.buttons button'));

function panelShow(e) {
  $("path").removeClass("active");
  var clickedPath = this.getElement();
  clickedPath.classList.add("active");
  var datum = (clickedPath.getAttribute('class').match(/\d+/g) || [])[0];
  buttons.forEach(function(btn) {
    var method = btn.getAttribute('data-date') === datum ? 'add' : 'remove';
    btn.classList[method]('active');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to get the `classList` of the clicked element and then iterate to find element with matching classes like

```
function panelShow(e) {
    var classes = this.getElement().getAttribute('class').split(" "); // Split to return array of all classes of the clicked element so we can loop through
    for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        var singleclass = document.querySelector("." + classes[i]);
        for(var j = 0; j < singleclass.length; j++){
            // Test if the element has the class 'active' before adding if it doesn't
            if(!(' ' + singleclass[j].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + 'active' + ' ') > -1)
                singleclass[j].className += ' active';
        };
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
My bad! As pointed out in the comment, I have updated my answer. My syntax was compeletly wrong as I forgot to split my class list and add **"."** to my `querySelector`! I am assuming you don't want to use jQuery for some reason. I hope this helps anyone.

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function(…)

Comment: **this.getAttribute('class')** returns a string not an array.  **querySelector()** expects CSS selectors and without a "." will be looking for a node not a class.  Even then it returns the first match not all matches.  This answer (other than the abstract description) is completely wrong.