# How to save a list of classes using javascript to compare them against other classes later?

Tags: javascript

I have a series of polygons :

```
<svg>
   <path class="_1600 _1500 _1400 leaflet"></path>
   <path class="_1300 _1700 _1900 leaflet"></path>
   <path class="_1600 _1400 _1800 leaflet"></path>
</svg>
```

And buttons:

```
<button class="_1600 _1500"></button>
<button class="_1600 _1300 _1200"></button>
<button class="_1300 _1200 _1700 _1800"></button>    
<button class="_1300 _1200 _1100 _1900"></button>
```

I need to assign a class to it on a click and this is how I do it and works fine:

On click:

```
    this.getElement().classList.add("active");
```

Now the polygons become:

```
<svg>
   <path class="_1600 _1500 _1400 leaflet"></path>
   <path class="active _1300 _1700 _1900 leaflet"></path>
   <path class="_1600 _1400 _1800 leaflet"></path>
</svg>
```

How can I save the list of classes of the clicked element (to which I also have added `.active` after a click)? 
I would like to save them so that I can later comprare this list for any match with another list of classes and if any match, attach a `.active` class to the matching elements.

I must use:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        click: panelShow
    });
}

function panelShow(e) {
    $("path").removeClass("active");
    this.getElement().classList.add('active');
}
```

Comment: just splice the classlist on active .now you get the list of classes except active...by this i guess you can compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
var buttons = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.buttons button'));

function panelShow(e) {
  $("path").removeClass("active");
  var clickedPath = this.getElement();
  clickedPath.classList.add("active");
  var datum = (clickedPath.getAttribute('class').match(/\d+/g) || [])[0];
  buttons.forEach(function(btn) {
    var method = btn.getAttribute('data-date') === datum ? 'add' : 'remove';
    btn.classList[method]('active');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) to get a space-separated string containing all the classes.

```
this.getElement().className;
```

If you want to have something more fancy, like a static `classList` copy, you can always create a dummy element:

```
function staticClassListCopy(element) {
  var dummy = document.createElement('div');
  dummy.className = element.className; // import classes
  return dummy.classList;
}
```

This object will be an array-like, so you can iterate it easily to do the desired comparisons.

Comment: ok but how do I compare them? I am trying to solve this, just tried to ask it in a different way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441754/mixing-javascript-with-jquery

Comment: You could additionally perform a `.split(" ")` on the result of `className` and now you have an array you can sort and compare.

Comment: @JorgeCabot But there can be edge cases, such that `className` returns multiple spaces as separators, then `.split(" ")` would think there is an empty class. And the normal space is not the only class separator, other whitespace like newlines also separate.

Comment: @Oriol I think `className` returns the list single spaced even if there are multiple spaces as written in the html `class` attribute. However, I'm not sure so there could be some exceptions as you mentioned.

Comment: I believe `.trim().split(/[\u0009\u000A\u000C\u000D\u0020]+/)` would work, but I prefer to let the browser do the parsing.

Comment: they are not fixed classes*