# How to compare a list of classes against other classes in html?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I save my list of classes attached to the element i click like this:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        click: panelShow
    });
}

function panelShow(e) {
    $("path").removeClass("active");
    this.getElement().classList.add("active");
    function staticClassListCopy(element) {
       var dummy = document.createElement('div');
       dummy.className = element.className;
       return dummy.classList;
    }
}
```

I have a list of buttons with classes like this:

```
<button class="1600 1500"></button>
<button class="1600 1300 1200"></button>
<button class="1300 1200 1700 1800"></button>    
<button class="1300 1200 1100 1900"></button>
```

Now I need to compare if in my saved list there is any class that matches any classes on the buttons and if so, add an `.active` class to those matching buttons.

Comment: what `staticClassListCopy` for?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest to be honest I am really trying to solve this as it is the main problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441754/mixing-javascript-with-jquery

Comment: What exactly  is the "saved list" here? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @undefined updated the question. The saved list is the class list attached to the clicked element

Comment: @undefined but then again, trying to solve this really http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441754/mixing-javascript-with-jquery

Comment: Yes, that provides more context. I'll read the question now.

Comment: @undefined thanks a lot, thing is from there I created other questions to just try to grab few more infos. But that is the real problem really

Comment: Does this help? https://jsfiddle.net/nhsxopj0/

Comment: I'm afraid no. Ok this is the link so you can test it, click on a map polygon and the buttons with same classes should also have an active class http://www.robertomarras.com/spimepin/

Comment: Why not? The other question says that this effect is "Desired after the div click". Now I'm confused! – I couldn't open the linked webpage: "This site can’t be reached".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127451/discussion-between-rob-m-and-undefined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery has the `toggleClass` feature, and from what it sounds like this is what you are trying to do.

```
$('button').toggleClass('active');
```

So, if the class exists on the button it will remove it otherwise it will add it.

You could even do something like this:

```
var list = ['.1600', '.1800'];

$('button').filter(list.join(',')).addClass('active');
```

Comment: I don't need it in jQuery

Comment: "You could even do something like this:". – No, `.has()` doesn't do what you think it does!